# How to return "UTC+XX:XX" or "UTC-XX:XX" format from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdate

I would like to know if there is standard method that could return current timezone of the devise in format "UTC+XX:XX" or "UTC-XX:XX"?

Based on formatting `NSDate` i know that it is possible to get current time zone with help of "ZZZZ", that gives "GMT-08:00".

The question is if there is special formatting for `NSDate` that will give "UTC-08:00" ?

Comment: @Rob thanx for answer could you please post you're answer so i could accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'UTC'ZZZZZ`, i.e. a literal string `UTC` followed by `ZZZZZ` (`-08:00`).

Answer (score 1):

Use NSDateFormatter, and set the time zone as part of configuring the formatter.